# Jaspersoft Studio; Cannot view the sub elements/components

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab, jaspersoft-studio

I am a relatively new user of Jaspersoft Studio and currently, I am trying to study it for the benefit of using it company wide in the future.

A thing that is bothering me and halting my productivty is that I can't access the sub-elements of my crosstab.

[image: This is a screen of my crosstab element]

I have placed it within the Summary tab. Searching throughout google, I have found the tutorial which has a picture (the below) showing you can edit the elements of the crosstab.

[image]

I was wondering how you can do that. I have observed that the example has no Bands (Title, Page Header, Column Header, etch.). I tried Imitating that by deleting all the bands but I can't seem to input the cross tab into the report.

Comment: Well after that, I had other problems such as how the program orders records, but that will be left for another question or research. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you need help, have fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, you need to **double click** the crosstab component in JasperSoft Studio to view *"Groups for rows,columns and measures"* in the outline